# Should I learn JavaFX for Android or Android Separately

Tags: java, android, ios, javafx

I'm learning JavaFX and learnt a lot to create Desktop Application.
Now I was deciding to go for Android App. But recently I read from the google search that I can create Android/iOS app in JavaFX. (Even watched video)

So my question is. 
Should I focus on to "**Learn JavaFX for Android**" or **should I start Learning Android separately**?

As I already read from the google and realized that JavaFX for the android will be better because we can run same code for Desktop, iOS, iPad and Android. But I want to ask from experts.

Comment: [Questions which are \[...\] primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok from where I can get the answer of such questions?

Comment: If you are interested in running javafx on android check out http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/

Comment: @sazzy4o I want to learn Android. But I want to ask which approach or way will be best? JavaFX for Android or Android Separately?

Comment: This question is kind of off topic but  I learned javafx and android seperately. I found that that gave me a better understanding of the inerworking of both and allowed me to make more adaptive and effecient programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with javaFx for android but its efficient to learn and work with android separately.it will help you a lot with its great, easy and most powerful  library support .